# Is there a AntPath matcher equivalent in Camel Blueprint

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

can't find anything on this online, anyone know how to do the equivalent in blueprint as per the following spring-camel beans setup :-

```
<!-- define our filter as a plain spring bean -->
<bean id="csvAntFilter" class="org.apache.camel.component.file.AntPathMatcherGenericFileFilter">
    <property name="includes" value="*.csv"/>
</bean>

<route>
  <from uri="file://inbox?filter=#csvAntFilter"/>
  <to uri="bean:processInbox"/>
</route>
```

My understanding (sorry still fairly limited with camel), is that AntPathMatcher is part of camel-spring and not camel-blueprint so can't use it this way if i want to use blueprint.

Or is there a better way to do this in blueprint ?

***Edit***
I've found that there exists camel-core-xml but unsure on how to utilise the AntPathMatcher within it.

Comment: Have ended up just using  file://<directory>?include=.*\.csv and all is good in the world again, would still like to know the way to use a filter with blueprint however, for future reference and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The Ant path matcher is part of camel-core, so you can use it with blueprint also. It used to be part of camel-spring but we moved it into the core, so people can use it without Spring, eg just Java or Blueprint etc.

Though it depends on which Camel version you use, if its in camel-core etc.